# Count records and print rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want mysql to select the record which has `SECRETKEY = 'ts17'` then count records in `tb_dailyshow` with `SECRETKEY = 'ts17'` AND `DATE = '20160608'` (if all the records in `tb_dailyshow` are less than `10` print `NAME` row from `tb_names` table).

First table `tb_names`

```
ID | SECRETKEY | NAME
---------------------
1  | ts17      | Chris
```

Second table `tb_dailyshow`

```
ID | SECRETKEY | DATE
--------------------
1  | ts17      | 20160608
2  | ts17      | 20160608
3  | fa99      | 20160608
```

my mysql line:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM tb_adv n 
INNER JOIN tb_shown ds 
ON ds.uid = n.uid 
  AND ds.date = '20160607' 
WHERE n.uid = '575474d715154' 
GROUP BY n.id 
HAVING COUNT(*)<10
```

php codes:

```
$q = "SELECT n.* 
FROM tb_adv n 
INNER JOIN tb_shown ds 
ON ds.uid = n.uid 
  AND ds.date = '20160607' 
WHERE n.uid = '575474d715154' 
GROUP BY n.id 
HAVING COUNT(*)<10";
$select = mysqli_query($con, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
  echo $row['text'];
}
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like, and show us your best effort to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/148e1e/1

```
SELECT n.*
FROM tb_names n
INNER JOIN tb_dailyshow ds
ON ds.secretkey = n.secretkey
  AND ds.date = '20160608'
WHERE n.secretkey = 'ts17'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(*)<10
```

To debug your code transform this part:

```
$select = mysqli_query($con, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
  echo $row['text'];
}
```

to this:

```
if($select = mysqli_query($con, $q)) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
    echo $row['text'];
  }
} else {
  echo "Query failed with error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

**Update** if you need to get record even if there is no `dailyshows` you can just change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6472a/3

```
SELECT n.*
FROM tb_names n
LEFT JOIN tb_dailyshow ds
ON ds.secretkey = n.secretkey
  AND ds.date = '20160608'
WHERE n.secretkey = 'ts18'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(*)<10
```

Comment: got this error `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...` What's wrong with this line?  `SELECT n.* FROM tb_adv n INNER JOIN tb_shown ds ON ds.uid = n.uid AND ds.date = '20160607' WHERE n.uid = '575474d715154' GROUP BY n.id HAVING COUNT(*)<10`

Comment: the error is not about query, but about function call `mysqli_fetch_array()` so provide your php code in your post

Comment: i added php codes to the post.

Comment: It works well `ds.date` must've been `ds.year`. thanks.

Comment: excuse me, when there's no record in `tb_shown` it doesnt print anything. even if it's `0` it has to print `tb_adv` records. please solve the rest...

Comment: check update. hope that will help

Comment: Thanks pretty helpful.

Comment: @BottledTurtles It's nice to upvote helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tb_names.name, count(*)
from tb_names 
join tb_dailyshow 
 on tb_names.secretkey = tb_dailyshow.secretkey 
where tb_dailyshow.date = '20160608'
group by tb_names.name
having count(*) < 10
```

Comment: If i understand correctly:  This will only show results if  count in tb_dailyshow is less than 10.

Comment: Note that this will however *not* show the name if count is `0`.

Comment: @richard Yes. this should show results from `tb_names`